# Unable to update my database table after editing cell from UI dataTable

Tags: java, jsf, jdbc

Here is my java code to update database table and editing cell from UI.

From UI for caption column to edit its fine but its not updating column values in database table.

```
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
    System.out.println("inside cell edit");

     UIColumn col=(UIColumn) event.getColumn();
    DataTable o = (DataTable) event.getSource();
    Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();
    LabelsVO info = (LabelsVO) o.getRowData();
    int newModel = info.getLang_no();
    int newData=info.getLabel_no();

    System.out.println("row index in event method " + event.getRowIndex());
    System.out.println("old value" + oldValue);
    System.out.println("new value" + newValue);
    System.out.println("column1 :" + col.getHeader());

    try {
        conn=Database.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("update ias_labels set caption_det =? where lang_no =? and label_no=?");
        stmt.setInt(1, newModel);
        stmt.setInt(2, newData);
        stmt.setString(3, newValue.toString());
        int rset = stmt.executeUpdate();
        conn.commit();
        if (rset != 0) {
            System.out.println("updated!!!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not updated!!!");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
```

---

here is my front end class

```
<p:layoutUnit position="center" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                    <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="lab" value="#{labelsMB.userLogList}" editable="true" editMode="cell"  
                                 paginator="true" rows="10"  
                                 paginatorTemplate="  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">  
                        <f:facet name="header">  
                            Labels Details
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:ajax event="cellEdit" immediate="true" listener="#{labelsMB.onCellEdit}" update="dataTable" />

                        <p:column headerText="Caption" sortBy="#{lab.caption_det}" filterBy="#{lab.caption_det}" width="40">  
                            <p:cellEditor>
                                <f:facet name="output">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{lab.caption_det}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="input">
                                    <h:inputText value="#{lab.caption_det}" style="width:96%"/>
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:cellEditor>
                            </p:column>

                        <p:column sortBy="#{lab.label_no}" filterBy="#{lab.label_no}" width="10">  
                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                <h:outputText value="Label No" />  
                            </f:facet>  
                            <h:outputText value="#{lab.label_no}" />  
                        </p:column>  
                        <p:column sortBy="#{lab.lang_no}" filterBy="#{lab.lang_no}" width="10">  
                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                <h:outputText value="Langauge No" />  
                            </f:facet>  
                            <h:outputText value="#{lab.lang_no}" /> 
                        </p:column> 
                        <p:column sortBy="#{lab.lang_name}" filterBy="#{lab.lang_name}" width="10">  
                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                <h:outputText value="Langauge Name" />  
                            </f:facet>  
                            <h:outputText value="#{lab.lang_name}" /> 
                        </p:column> 
                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <p:commandButton id="dataTable" icon="ui-icon-disk" iconPos="left" ajax="false" value="Save" action="#{labelsMB.onCellEdit(event)}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: If there is an exception then please show us the stacktrace. Are you sure, that your SQL insert code is executed (stepping with debugger)? What is the return value of `executeUpdate()`? Are you sure, there are records present fulfilling the where clause of your SQL statement? If you execute the very same SQL statement (including actual parameter values) with a SQL console, is there the expected effect?

Comment: am getting same value as what i have in databse value after executing and debugging.....even am getting error is coloumn index is invalid number here  executeUpdate() ...i dont no what is this..

Comment: If you got an error, please show us the full stack trace! Otherwise it is impossible to help you.

Comment: ultimate
inside cell edit
inside cell edit
row index in event method 3
old valuenewValue
new valuenewValue
column1 :null
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
 at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
 ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.ultimate.managedBeans.LabelsMB.onCellEdit(LabelsMB.java:99)

Comment: 15-Mar-2016 18:16:58.326 WARNING [http-nio-9999-exec-12] com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute #{labelsMB.onCellEdit(event)}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 javax.faces.FacesException: #{labelsMB.onCellEdit(event)}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
- Stack Trace

javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
 at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
 at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)

Comment: So the database error is ["ORA-01722: invalid number"](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-01722#When_doing_an_INSERT_INTO_..._VALUES_.28....29). It seems you tried to insert a string for a number column. What is the datatype of column `label_no`?

Comment: datatype of column label_no is NUMBER

Comment: datatype of column lang_no is NUMBER .....datatype of column caption_det is VARCHAR